# Run HTML Tidy in batch on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, html, shell-script

I want to run HTML Tidy on a large number of files located in folders and subfolders. I can use the following command in Terminal to run it on a single file:

```
tidy -f errors.txt -m -utf8 -i sample.html
```

But how can I run it specifying a root folder and have it go through each of the html files in there, and then do the same on each subfolder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `find`.

```
find /path/to/folder -type f -name "*.html" -exec tidy -f errors.txt -m -utf8 -i {} \;
```

This will run `tidy` on all `.html` files in the specified folder:

- `-type f` matches all *files* (as opposed to folders, symbolic links, etc.)
- `-name "*.html"` matches all files with `.html` extension
- `-exec tidy -f errors.txt -m -utf8 -i {} \;` runs the specified `tidy` command line, with the full file path inserted at `{}`. `\;` is required by `find` to terminate this command.